# modify url and forward in session validation filter - websphere portal 8

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, websphere, websphere-8, websphere-portal

After following all the steps from IBM docs for friendly url's, I'm getting this kind of URL all over the portal

> http://example.com/wps/portal/account/account-login#Z7_JH56H4K0KO8C00ACRD944B2042

with a # appended value. I somehow managed to clear that using JavaScript. I know that is not a proper solution and I'm not satisfied. I fully doubt on a state pattern which is used in the project, unfortunately its written long back and I don't have its source. The only thing which I got in mind is SessionValidationFilter. I am able to get the request url, modify and could redirect also. But I cant keep redirecting for every request as I need request parameters. Someone please point me in right direction to forward request from sessionvalidation filter. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you see there is a Fragment Identifier. Defined in IETF in RFC 1866, which states:

> 7.4. Fragment Identifiers
>
> Any characters following a `#' character in a hypertext address
>   constitute a fragment identifier. ...
>
> The user agent should indicate the anchor element, for example by
>   scrolling to and/or highlighting the phrase.
>
> For example, if the base URI is `http://host/x/y.html' and the user
>   activated the link denoted by the following markup:
>
> See: appendix 1    for more
>   detail on bananas.
>
> Then the user agent accesses the resource identified by
>   `http://host/x/app1.html'. ... the user agent must locate the <A>
>
>   element whose NAME attribute is`bananas' and begin navigation there.

You should not see the fragment inside of the http traffic to the server.
In my case it has been the objectid of a Portlet where Portal wanted to bring the focus back too. Like you see above the anchor tag where the browser would try to scroll to the anchor.

It is possible to disable this behaviour on a per portlet base. The portlet preference to set is wps.fragment.identifier with a value of false. you can either define it in the portlet.xml or it should be possible to have it added as a parameter inside of the config section of the Portlet. 
So you should search for the Portlet with the objectid and modify its settings